# Executar run-app esta retornando erro

Tags: grails

Tenho um projeto de 3 anos atraz, e preciso atualiza-lo para gerar um .war e coloca-lo rodando em cima do Tomcat, porem quando executo o comando grails run-app esta me retornando o seguinte erro:

> | Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer
>   artifact org.gr ails.plugins:uploadr:zip:1.0.0 from/to grailsCentral
>   (http://repo.grails.org/gra ils/plugins):  (416) (Use --stacktrace to
>   see the full trace) | Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies:
>   Could not transfer artifact org.gr ails.plugins:uploadr:zip:1.0.0
>   from/to grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/gra ils/plugins):  (416)
>   (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace) | Error Resolve error
>   obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact org.gr
>   ails.plugins:uploadr:zip:1.0.0 from/to grailsCentral
>   (http://repo.grails.org/gra ils/plugins):  (416) (Use --stacktrace to
>   see the full trace) | Error Could not transfer artifact
>   org.grails.plugins:uploadr:zip:1.0.0 from/to  grailsCentral
>   (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins):  (416)

Imagino que seja alguma dependência que não tenha mais repositório. E a mensagem de erro é muito maior quando uso do parâmetros --stacktrace --verbose caso seja necessário posso actualizar minha pergunta.

Mas gostaria de saber se alguem sabe como corrigir isso?

**UPDATE**

Sei que o erro é com esse plugin, porem não faço ideia de porque ele não acha o repositorio e como concertar, fazer o dowload no git ou algo assim, se alguem podesse me falar um passo a passo ficaria muito grato.

```
compile ":uploadr:1.0.0"
```

Comment: Bom o plugin que esta utilizando e o de upload acredito eu
https://grails.org/plugin/uploadr?skipRedirect=true Qual a versao do grails que voce esta utilizando? Tentou remover este plugin? Me passa algumas informacoes para que eu possa te ajudar =]

Comment: O plugin acredito que seja esse https://github.com/4np/grails-uploadr, a versão do grails 2.4.3, não tentei remover porque depende muitas partes no projeto dele, Vou ser eternamente grato a ti!!!